# React native reload child component

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have 2 screen A and Screen B. Screen A has a sub component `SomeList` which loads data and i just pass the action to the subcomponent and it does the rest.Currently by design of react-navigation no action on revisit. I googled and came across https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html but not sure how to use it to reload SomeList when i navigate from ScreenB to ScreenA.

ScreenA

```
class ScreenA extends Component {

   render() {
    return (
      <SomeList
        loadData={this.props.actions.getAlllist}
      />
    )
}
```

ScreenB

```
Class ScreenB extends Component {

    someAction = () => {
       this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenA")
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, What you want it's to load the data on `<SomeList/>` component when you are in screen A, but when you navigate to screen B  and then back to screen A, you want to be able to load new data right?

Comment: @CarlosAbraham Yes sir

Answer (score -1):

Due to react-native's design, I think you'd be better off passing data to your child Component.

Here's how you can do this:

```
   class ScreenA extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {
            data: [],
          }
          this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this.load)
          this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', this.unmount)
        }

       load = ()=>{
          const _data = this.props.actions.getAlllist;
          this.setState({data:_data})
       }
       unmount = ()=>{
          this.setState({data:[]})
       }
       render() {
        return (
          <SomeList
            dataArray ={this.state.data}
          />
        )
    }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fetch data each time you render something, you can use **componentDidMount** lifecycle method

```js
class ScreenA extends Component {
   state = {
     data: [];
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     this.setState({ data: this.props.actions.getAlllist });
   }

   render() {
    return <SomeList loadData={this.state.data}/>;
}
```

So every time the **ScreenA** screen it's rendered it will fetch the data.

Comment: ComponentDidMount() triggers only when the component is mounted, not every time the View comes in foreground